# Additional cache management buttons not showing after magento upgrade

Tags: magento2.3

I upgraded magento 2.2 to 2.3.7. After upgrade Additional Cache Management buttons missing.
If anyone know reason for this, please suggest me some idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why but **/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/system/cache** was empty.

Uploaded **additional.phtml and edit.phtml** from version 2.3.7 and its fixed now.